# Ubuntu 13.04 Multi Monitor Dell precision m4600 nvidia optimus

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I've been fighting for two days now trying to get mulitmonitor support for the my dell precision m6400 with a nvidia quadro 1000m.

I recently saw that Nvidia's 319 drivers supported optimus, so naively I went in bright eyed and bushy tailed down the rabbit hole...

I am currently in a docking station using 2 external monitors (over DVI) connected to the dock and I'd like to use the laptop screen as my 3rd monitor.

I've tried using bumblebee and not, I've tried using the xorg.config I found on nvidia's website, I've tried using the ubuntu software center's additional drivers section. My machine is in such a bad state, I'm not sure where to go from here.

There was a time when I was able to get just get the two external monitors with a blank laptop screen and even getting back to that would be a huge.

Any advice would be really appreciated. Please let me knwo what further information is required to help solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what package of nvidia did you try ?

there is acutally a newer package of nvidia-driver
for optimus Cuda cards : NVIDIA_CUDA_SDK_1.1_Beta_Linux.run

Comment: As of yesterday, I tried 3 times, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 erasing everything and starting from scratch. I followed up by doing all the software updates. Then I made sure to be using the 3.9.0 kernal, xrandx 1.4, and Xserver 1.13. When I installed the beta drivers. I lost the unity launcher and menubar, as well as the ability to use the laptop mouse (usb mouse still works). Do I need to install NVIDIA_CUDE_SDK_1.1_Beta_Linux.run on top of the 319.23 drivers?

Comment: here is an "off-topic" link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/297030/nvidia-frickle-with-hybrid-chipset-is-now-over-finally   I had very many attempts too. But these steps are the solution, which is working here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you turn off optimus (BIOS settings) and reinstall from scratch. I have the same machine and it's a nightmare. The downside is the impact it has to battery life. In my case, I value stability more than power efficiency

Comment: If you disable optimus completely can you even use the external monitors? With my latitude dock external monitors don't seem to be usable at all without bumblebee

Comment: It depends on the laptop. I don't have a dock, so I can't check your specific issue on my m4600 (Quadro 1000M). Disabling optimus doesn't affect video connections (vga, hdmi or dp) in my case

Comment: If I turn optimus off I can still us the external monitors through the dock. I was just hoping to get all three installed.